# "M-s-h" is being interpreted as "M-s-˙"

Tags: keystrokes

When I type `M-s-h` emacs reports: `M-s-˙ is undefined`

That tiny dot is the [`'DOT ABOVE' (U+02D9)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02d9/index.htm) character.

I'm on OS X. This is happening when I use the [emacs-plus](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus) build. With [emacs-mac port](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport) I don't see this behavior.

Is there any way for me to debug this?

Comment: How are your modifier keys set up? I'm guessing that Alt is meta, and Command is super, is that right? Then the problem is likely that Alt-h is DOT ABOVE. How to work around that, I don't know, but the documentation for emacs-plus (which I don't use) ought to tell.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You nailed it. It is indeed Alt-h sending DOT ABOVE.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a problem because some part of this keystroke is interpreted as that letter. Try typing it (like you did in Emacs and using other modifiers) in some other text editor or another thing where you can type in using your input methods, and check your keyboard settings.

> I would comment this, but the reputation system here is pretty bad, and I can't even help people if I wanted to.